# How to combine bloc and sqlite?

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc, sqflite

I'm developing a shoping food app. This is the part of my code of databaseProvider class.

```
Future<List<CartItem>> getAllItems() async {
  Database db = await database;
  final List<Map<String, dynamic>> map = await db.query(tableName);
  return List.generate(map.length, (index) {
   return CartItem.fromMap(map[index]);
  });
}

Future<void> addItemToCart(CartItem item) async {
  final db = await database;
  await db.insert(tableName, item.toMap());
}

Future<void> removeItemFromCart(String id) async {
  final db = await database;
  await db.delete(tableName, where: 'id = ?', whereArgs: [id]);
}
```

I want to use flutter_bloc (or cubit) for state management. By clicking on the "Add to cart" button, I want to save the product information to the database. And on the other screen (cart screen) I want the saved product data to be displayed. But I don't understand what methods need to be created in the bloc.
I guess I should create some states (LoadInformaton, ProductAdded, ProductRemoved) and events (AddProduct, RemoveProduct). But how to combine this in bloc.dart file with sqlite methods?

I will be glad of any help!

Comment: Why the need to use state management since you are already using SQLite (via `sqflite` package I assume)? I would use SQLite for all state management.

Comment: In your bloc, you can call addItemToCart method onProductAdded, so it will be in your database. After that call you can trigger LoadAllItemsInCart event so the cart will be updated as well. You can emit a new state with updated Cart items and update your UI accordingly.